# Render list on template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create some graphics in my template with data from my models. I'm doing a survey app. Each survey has some questions, and each question has some answers. The user answer each question. So I count the answer for each question. I want to plot these answers in my template.

I'm using this view to count the data and render to template:

```
def SurveyResults(request, id):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        quest_survey = Survey.objects.get(id=2)
        quests = quest_survey.questions()
        graphic = {}
        graphic_id = 1
        if quests:
            for quest in quests: 
                a1 = AnswerSelect.objects.filter(question_id=quest.id, body = "answer 1").count()
                a2 = AnswerSelect.objects.filter(question_id=quest.id, body = "answer 2").count()
                a3 = AnswerSelect.objects.filter(question_id=quest.id, body = "answer 3").count()
                a4 = AnswerSelect.objects.filter(question_id=quest.id, body = "answer 4").count()
                graphic[str(graphic_id)] = [['answer1', a1], ['answer2', a2], ['answer3', a3], ['answer4', a4] ]
                graphic_id += 1

            return render(request, 'results.html', locals())
        else:
            msg = "A Survey não possui questões"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('profile.html')
    else:
        msg = "Usuario ou senha digitados incorretamente"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('home.html', {'msg': msg})
```

The question is, how can I get the values of graphic["1"],...,graphic["n"] in my template?

I'm trying to do this:

```
{% if graphic %}
        {% for g in graphic %}
            {% for item in g %}
                {{ item }}
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But instead of the data, I only get the value of the ids: 1,2,...,n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items` function to display the keys and values of the dictionary in template:

```
{% for key, value in graphic.items %}
    {% for item in value %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution doesn't work properly. {{ item }} doesn't return item[1], item[2],...,item[n] in a separate way. Instead, I'm getting each answer separately which doesn't allow me to make the plot.

Comment: Already solved. I wanted just the first for and print value. It wasn't necessary the second for and print item. Thanks!